# Why a CrowBar is called a Crowbar?

Tags: power

I know the naming can be funny , but still it amuses me why a over voltage protection circuit is called a crow bar .                 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowbar_(circuit)

Comment: Which part of the very first paragraph of the Wikipedia article is not clear? *"... much as if one were to drop a [crowbar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowbar_(tool)) across the output terminals of the power supply."*

Comment: I think the Wikipedia sentence is just plain stupid. Why not screwdriver circuit? That would be more likely with the small power-supplies I normally work with. To me crowbar is more descriptive of the fuse and the mechanism that makes it blow (ripping the power off the circuit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which part of the very first paragraph of the Wikipedia article is not clear?

> ... much as if one were to drop a [crowbar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowbar_(tool)) across the output terminals of the power supply.

The notion is that a steel crowbar is more rugged than anything else in the circuit, so it diverts all of the available current, unconditionally protecting the downstream circuit while simultaneously forcing something else in the upstream circuit (hopefully a fuse or circuit breaker) to burn out or trip off.

Comment: Of course that also implied you use the American name for the device.... One could just as easily also call it a Jimmy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowbar_(tool)

Comment: @Trevor: Either style of "crowbar" (American or English) works in this context.

Comment: True, but the OP does have a point. It is rather amusing we happened to settle on that particular tool that we all have in our little EE tool-chests. NOT..

Comment: @Trevor: I'm pretty sure that the term dates from the days when a crowbar would have been a common tool for an EE to carry -- for shifting large generators, motors, transformers, batteries, etc. into position, among other things (general "percussive maintenance" :-). Have you ever seen what happens when you literally drop a crowbar across the battery bus in a telephone exchange? It's rather memorable!

Comment: Yes I understand all that and concur wholeheartedly. On the other hand.. if you happen to come near my work bench and drop a crowbar on my power supply.... which I have no doubt would do a lot more damage than just shorting out the terminals... I might whack you with it.. LOL But English is a funny language in general ;)

Comment: @Trevor - It's not funny language that's involved (although yes, English does weird things), it's history. The use of "crowbar" much predates our puny little workbenches, and originated with electrical power generating plants, where heavy iron (and copper) ruled. Like, when a power bus meant bussbars, and current meant thousands of amps. Under these conditions, a wimpy little screwdriver would vaporize.

Answer (score 2):

From Wikibooks:

> Crowbar circuits are so named because their activation is similar in effect to dropping a crowbar across bus bars (heavy duty power supply lines).

Answer (score 1):

A crowbar is so called as its shape matches or is at least similar to the leg / foot shape of the crow... to answer the question in the title ...

Answer (score 0):

I was told by an old instructor of mine the term came from actual use in broadcast antenna facilities with huge power supplies they would use an actual crowbar to short the bus and protect the power supply and other circuit when the antenna was disconnected.